# Having trouble with NSCalendar get date components

Tags: ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

So I have an NSCalendar and do some tests:

First, change system time zone to `America/Los_Angeles (GMT-8)`, giving a unix time stamp `1455552000000`, convert it to NSDate: by

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1455552000000 / 1000];
```

It returns `2016-02-15 16:00:00 +0000`

And then use the calendar to generate the date components:

```
+(void)applyCalendarToCurrentTimeZone:(NSCalendar *)calendar {
    if (![calendar.timeZone isEqualToTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]) {
        calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    }
}

+ (NSDateComponents *)getDateComponentsFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateComponents *components;
    static NSCalendar *ISO8601 = nil;
    static NSCalendarUnit unit;
    if (!ISO8601) {
        ISO8601 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601];
        ISO8601.firstWeekday = 2; // Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7
        ISO8601.minimumDaysInFirstWeek = 7;
        unit = NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitQuarter|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    }

    [ChartModel applyCalendarToCurrentTimeZone:ISO8601];

    components = [ISO8601 components:unit fromDate:date];
    return components;
}
```

But while debugging, I found problem,

At first, everything looks fine, the date components are correct, the `Day` value is `15` in GMT-8 time zone.

```
(lldb) po ISO8601.timeZone
America/Los_Angeles (GMT-8) offset -28800

(lldb) po date
2016-01-18 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po ISO8601.timeZone
America/Los_Angeles (GMT-8) offset -28800

(lldb) po date
2016-02-15 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po [ISO8601 components:unit fromDate:date];
<NSDateComponents: 0x13e4ae530>
    Calendar Year: 2016
    Month: 2
    Leap month: no
    Day: 15
    Hour: 8
    Minute: 0
    Second: 0
    Quarter: 0
    Year for Week of Year: 2016
    Week of Year: 7

(lldb)
```

Without restarting app, change system time zone to auto, since I am in Beijing, it is GMT+8, and refresh data, the date components looks fine too, the `Day` value is `16` in Shanghai time zone.

```
(lldb) po ISO8601.timeZone
Local Time Zone (Asia/Shanghai (GMT+8) offset 28800)

(lldb) po date
2016-02-15 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po [ISO8601 components:unit fromDate:date];
<NSDateComponents: 0x13ec15150>
    Calendar Year: 2016
    Month: 2
    Leap month: no
    Day: 16
    Hour: 0
    Minute: 0
    Second: 0
    Quarter: 0
    Year for Week of Year: 2016
    Week of Year: 7

(lldb)
```

Again, without restarting app, change back system time zone to GMT-8, now weird thing happens, the `Day` value is `16` in GMT-8 time zone, which is not corret! What did I miss? Please help!

```
(lldb) po ISO8601.timeZone
Local Time Zone (America/Los_Angeles (GMT-8) offset -28800)

(lldb) po date
2016-02-15 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po [ISO8601 components:unit fromDate:date];
<NSDateComponents: 0x13f888260>
    Calendar Year: 2016
    Month: 2
    Leap month: no
    Day: 16
    Hour: 0
    Minute: 0
    Second: 0
    Quarter: 0
    Year for Week of Year: 2016
    Week of Year: 7

(lldb)
```